# Raise 404 on .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web forms application (IIS 7) where I am using URL routing to allow friendly URLs.  For example, instead of `Blog.aspx?title=the-blog-title`, I allow `Blog/the-blog-title`.

My question is:  How do I prevent users from directly accessing Blog.aspx?  I have included the following setting in my web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This works, but it shows a 'This type of page is not served' error.  Is it possible to simply display a 404 error for all .aspx page requests using IIS or web.config?  (I know how to do this programatically, but I would prefer to use a config file if possible.)

Comment: may be *.asp is a true filter and get /the-blog-title as /the-blog-title/Default.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to change the offending addresses to those you prefer.  Here's an article [explaining the difference](http://coderjournal.com/2010/03/difference-between-routing-rewriting/) between the two ideas.

**SEO aspects of URL Rewriting**

URL Rewriting does not dilute SEO; in fact, that is how you establish [canonical URLs](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/), by rewriting the URL.  Search engines only see the rewritten URL, not the URL used for the request.

For example, if you have the following URLs that all point to your homepage:

- http://example.com/
- http://example.com/default.aspx
- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/default.aspx

Then, you can rewrite the URL so anyone requesting any of the above URLs will be given the URL `http://www.example.com/`.  This URL is the only one that would be seen by search engines, regardless of how the page was initially accessed.

**How Rewriting Works**

When you request a URL, whether that is for `example.com/blog.aspx` or `example.com/blog`, the request is sent to the web server.  There, the URL rewrite engine evaluates the URL in the request headers.  If the URL matches any rewrite rules (for example, to remove the `.aspx` extension), then the web server issues a `301 Permanently Moved` response code, with the new URL in the response header.

After receiving the response, the browser requests the new URL.  Search engine bots like `googlebot` see the permanent redirect code and changes the index of that link to the requested URL.  So, if it has indexed `example.com/blog.aspx`, or anyone links to it, the `301 Permanently Moved` response tells the spider that the new URL is actually `example.com/blog`.  Therefore, in the eyes of the spider, `example.com/blog.aspx` is `example.com/blog`.

This is how people move websites and pages around without losing PageRank, because the rewrite engine points the spiders to the new page, so the new page name keeps the same PageRank as the old page name.

URL Rewriting is also how sites can be accessed using, to take this site as an example, `www.stackoverflow.com` and have the browser actually show `stackoverflow.com` (without the `www`).  The rewrite engine tells the browser (and the spider) that references to `www.stackflow.com` are actually called `stackoverflow.com`.

---

While you have already found a solution with which you are happy, I'd highly recommend spending some time looking at URL Rewriting, as it is a more elegant and professional solution than sending error messages.  It'll also allow you to redirect all `non-www` requests to the `www` url, further preventing dilution of your SEO ranking.

Comment: I want to reject all requests for .aspx pages to prevent dilution of my SEO.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  Please explain how the search engine only sees the rewritten URL.  For example, if site 1 links to my blog via http://www.host.com/blog.aspx and site 2 links to my blog via http://www.host.com/blog, although they may serve the exact same content doesn't the search engine index both requests differently?  This is the reason that I want to prevent direct access to the .aspx file and service only friendly URLs.

Comment: Ah yes you didn't originally mention the redirection.  That's different than URL rewriting. :)  Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just implement a custom HTTP handler and return a 404.

```
public class PageNotFoundHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;

        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

And in web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="PageNotFoundHttpHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

EDIT:

Providing a 301 redirection per saluce's answer is a more elegant solution.  Although the URL rewrite/redirection depends more on the particular web server, in my case I am using IIS 7 and the URL Rewrite module is very good.